# Run emulator on macOS

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, haxm

I found questions like this on Google but none is working for my case. Here is a screenshot of my Android SDK Manager:

[image: SDK Manager screenshot]

And info of my virtual device:

```
Name: Pixel_API_25

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: /Users/....../.android/avd/Pixel_API_25.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 25)

Skin: pixel

SD Card: /Users/....../.android/avd/Pixel_API_25.avd/sdcard.img

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 25

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: none

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Pixel_API_25

hw.camera.front: none

hw.lcd.density: 480

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel API 25

hw.gpu.mode: host

hw.device.hash2: MD5:70f950b0b2b8960d1990af72fb74ad27

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

PlayStore.enabled: false

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

When I try to run the AVD a progress bar appears at the bottom of Android Studio and then nothing happens. I tried installing HAXM separately from Intel's website , removing `sdk` folder from `Library` then installing again neither worked.

How can I run emulator on my macOS?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Genymotion. Give it a try. It is faster and better.